# Terminology in Viro et al.

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I'm working through this book (Elementary Topology) and skimming the first section to make sure I'm not missing anything important to begin an independent study in algebraic topology, and I've come across this notation in several places, and I can't find a definition for it. It first appears on page 59 at the bottom, and reads

A map $f: X \rightarrow Y $ is continuous iff ab$(f): X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.
What is ab$(f)$?

Comment: I would guess it's the absolute value of $f$.

Comment: Look at the preceeding page at the top. :-) I will also give an answer.

Comment: Also it is not $Y$ the second time but $f(X)$

Comment: @DavidMitra: so what do you mean by the absolute value when $Y$ is any space?

Comment: @313 Looks like I guessed wrong...

Comment: @DavidMitra: yes, but in any case it was very hard to guess, and the "concept" of an "abbreviation" is totally nonstandard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This denotes the abbreviation of $f$. For a map $f:X\to Y$ and subsets $A \subset X$ and $f(A) \subset B \subset Y$ the abbreviation of $f$ is just the map from $A $ to $B$ defined by $x \mapsto f(x)$.

Roughly speaking, it is just $f$ with a more restricted domain and codomain; but as a map also depends on its domain and codomain on should not continue to call it $f$ if one is precise.

This generalizes the restriction of a map, often denoted $f|_A$ where only the domain is changed from $X$ to $A$ and the codomain is left unchanged.

This is defined on page 58 of the book mentioned in the question.

Comment: Oh. So it is. Woops.